# How to record screencast in Kitkat?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I used this command for taking screecast in Kitkat :

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

But instead of starting the recording, the phone shut down with this in cmd :

**WARNING: linker: libsavscmn.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and
is a security risk. Please fix.**

Comment: The command you have is fine, assuming that external storage is available at `/sdcard` on your device. What device are you using?

Comment: You may want to take up your issue with Samsung, then, as AFAIK that device has not yet been officially released.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Thanks! The command works fine in other devices. It maybe some device related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the command to:
adb shell screenrecord /storage/extsdCard/title.mp4

It will still give you an error, but it will in fact be recording so just check the SD card for the file. I'm not sure if this works on the note but I can confirm it works on the Samsung Galaxy S4 since I did it about 5 minutes ago. Also keep in mind I did this from a Windows 8.1 computer, not any form of osX.